# Can you suggest better Django model design? (I'm django beginner)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm designing a simple Django model called **Clothes**. Basically it retrieves what kinds of clothes the user have. I categorized clothes as more than 20 types (such as hoodies, jean, pants) and as big three types: "top", "bottom", "shoes".

In **ClothesView**, I want to show first 5 clothes for each "top", "bottom", "shoes". And it will retrieve 5 more for individual category if user clicks more (So if user click 'more top', it will return 5 more clothes of 'top' type.

For your better understanding, I wrote the **Clothes** model conceptually.

```
class Clothes(models.Model):
    id
    type =           # hoodie, shirts, pants, jean, coat, and so on (more than 20)
    big_type =      # top, bottom and shoes 
    owner = ForeignField  # some one who post
```

Expected output (this is just my guess!)

1. Retrieve 5 clothes for each parent_types ("top", "bottom", "shoes")

   ```
   user.clothes_set.filter(big_type="top")[:5]
   user.clothes_set.filter(big_type="bottom")[:5]
   user.clothes_set.filter(big_type="shoes")[:5]
   ```
2. Retrieved 5 more clothes for "top"

   ```
   user.clothes_set.filter(big_type="top)[5:10]
   ```
3. Retrieve all "hoodies" from my clothes <- this looks ok

   ```
   user.clothes_set.filter(type="hoodies")
   ```

**Can you suggest better of efficient model?** I may add new Type class and put "through" ... (I'm not sure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are doing it right. Read here, [limiting-queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets).

- If you want to query the database in this way. This is the good option instead of retrieving the whole `queryset` and then slicing it. Through this, the `LIMIT` for slicing will be issued to the database so, slicing will be done in the database.
- On the second opinion, I would advise you to create a new model for `Types` with the fields `type` and `id`.
  Then, map it using `ManyToMany Relation`, if you are not in the case.

For that querying may look like this,

```
type = Type.objects.get(type="Top").id
clothes = Clothes.objects.filter(type=type)[:5]
```

Having a different model for `Type` will help you at the client side rendering.